# Is it possible to create a tree of objects in Java?

Tags: java, tree

I am trying to create a tree of Objects in Java. I also want to use a Java class that makes it easy to add or remove nodes from the tree. What would be the best class to use for this purpose?

Example: Here is an array of objects. The object at the top of the array is the string "world". The leaves are integers here, and I want to add the string "This is at (world, 0, 0)!" as a leaf at "(world, 0, 0)". What Java class would be best for this purpose?

```
"world"
  /\
 0  1
/ \  /\
0 1  0 1
```

Comment: You describe the leaves being integers, but then the leaves being strings "(world, 0, 0)". Should it be one or the other?

Comment: @oconnor0 I'm trying to create a tree of Objects (which can be of any type). It's possible to do this in Java, isn't it?

Comment: Absolutely. Just use `Object` instead of a specific type. I wasn't sure if you wanted something more specific.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make your own.  It's easy.  Super super easy:

```
public class Tree{
    public Node root;
}

public class Node{
    public ArrayList<Node> children;
    public Node parent;
    public String value;
}
```

Now, putting a string value with a sequence of integers would be done something like this:

```
public class Tree{
    public String put(String value, int[] path){
        Node current = root;
        for(int i=0;i<path.length;i++){
            if(current.children.get(i)==null){
                current.children.add(i, new Node());
            }
            current = current.children.get(i);
        }
        String ret = current.value;
        current.value = value;
    }
}
```

Getting the value would be similar, except that you wouldn't overwrite the current value with a given value.

A description of what `put` does in English:

- Go to the n<sup>th</sup> child of the current node, where n is the next value in your path.
- If the child doesn't exist, create it.
- Repeat until the end of the path is reached.
- Return the current value (optional)
- Set the value to the new value.

So using this would look something like this:

```
Tree myTree = new Tree();
myTree.root = new Node();
int[] path = {0, 0, 0};
myTree.put("hi", path);
System.out.println(myTree.get(path));
```

And you'll get "hi" in your console.

Comment: The values are sometimes String's and sometimes int's.  But the question is not really clear...

Comment: The great thing about it is, it's so easy to change to whatever you need it to be.  I love being able to code my own stuff without having to look for libraries for everything.

Comment: If you need to store different kinds of objects, you could always make the value type Object instead of String, or you could use generics


class Tree{
    public Node<?> root;
}

class Node<T extends Object> {
        public ArrayList<Node<?>> children=new ArrayList<Node<?>>();
        public Node<?> parent;
        public T value;
}

Comment: I still need to find out how to add and remove nodes from a tree like this.

Comment: @Andy You should describe what you are trying to do more accurately.  How can you search and order such a tree with mixed numbers and Strings?

Comment: I basically want the tree to act like an array with an infinite number of dimensions. So if the statement add("Hi!", 0, 0, 0) were executed, then get(0, 0, 0) would return the string "Hi!".

Answer (score 2):

This sounds vaguely like homework. Is it? It's usually better to be up front about it if it is.

There's not really a data structure in Java that will do what you want, since it seems like you're interested in direct tree manipulation. The Java collections are more about the abstract data type provided (List, Set, Map) than the specifics of the backing implementation; the differing implementations are provided for their different performance characteristics.

In summary, you're probably best off writing your own. Unless all you really care about is mapping from one key to a value, then any of the Map implementations will do well.

Comment: This isn't homework; it's part of a fractal generator that I'm creating for a game. I want the fractal to be represented by a tree data structure, since using nested arrays is too cumbersome.

Comment: I basically want the tree to act like an array with an infinite number of dimensions, and I want to create "getter" and "setter" methods for the tree. So if the statement add("Hi!", 0) were executed, then something get(0) should return the string "Hi!". Then, the statement set(1, 0, 0) would add the integer 1 as the 0th leaf of the node (0).