# Create "file-system" structure in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, filesystems

I'm creating a Java web app in Google App Engine which uses the services of a cloud storage provider (i.e. Dropbox) to get info about the files of an user (in JSON format), adds some kind of info and presents them to the user.

To do this, I need to "copy" the files and folders from dropbox to a data structure in my app. I'd like to have them in memory while the user is connected, and then I have to store them with JDO.

I have my classes File and Folder (extending from my class Item), and I'd like to create a kind of tree structure to store them. I know there're TreeSet and TreeMap classes, and also I can create a custom tree like explained [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278391/is-it-possible-to-create-a-tree-of-objects-in-java).

So, can you say what's the most suitable (and simplest) way to do this?

Comment: I didn't try anything, this isn't a question of kind "I get an error with...", it's kind of "you expert people have a little advice to tackle this?". I'm looking for advice in the design, not in the implementation...

Comment: Unfortunately, MikO,  StackOverflow  isn't a good website for this kind of discussion.  The  site is specifically for figuring out how to deal with specific errors or situations that have a definite,  objective answer.  You asked an interesting question for sure,  but you might not get a good response on  StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin, for sure I knew that and I knowingly ran the risk of not getting a good response and even being downvoted (as in fact happened), but I hoped that someone could make a good suggestion as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

A Directory has an ArrayList of directories/files contained within it.

A File has a byte[] for its data.

Your FileSystemTree has one root Directory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason to roll your own File and Folder classes.  You can reuse the existing java.io.File object to represent the tree structure for the data.  Now all you need to do is attach the File data to the objects.  Probably a simple Map<File,String> would do the trick.  When you load the user data, create a File to represent the data and map the File to the data in memory.  When you go to store the data, walk the File tree structure and load from the map to your storage.